# How to setup multiple authenticators for users

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I'm writing an application in PHP using Yii. I'm trying to add the ability for users to be able to be authenticated differently.

My main question is what is the best way to go about it.

For example, I was thinking of doing something like so:

Have a table of Authenticators in a database that correlates to classes.

In the users table, have an authenticator id column that correlates to an authenticator.

This is about where I get stuck. I'm trying to be a Yii as possible here and use ActiveRecord. Each authenticator would need to know the users ID, so I'd have to pass that to the authenticator model (that stores the class name) and then find a way to pull the actual class, while passing the user to that as well.

All this seems a bit ... over kill.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Kyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your own descendant of CUserIdentity which implements Factory pattern. Sounds difficult, but I think there's no short answer at all.

Comment: I realized after submitting this question that I was going about everything all wrong and it made no real sense to tie multiple authenticators to a single user ID ... I'm not sure where I got the idea, but after my epiphany, I scrapped the idea. However, your answer is closest to my actual question, which is why I picked your as the answer since that makes the most sense on how to implement such a strategy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have all your answers in this topic: [Authentication and Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.auth).

Answer (score 0):

i'm suggesting you to use rbac approach and the easiest way is to use [right](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights) module.